# What does it mean to say that someone has unlimited credit?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was reading about the meaning of the word "credit" and saw the following definition and example:

Credit: The ability of a customer to obtain goods or services before payment, based on the trust that payment will be made in the future.

Example:Essentially, the idea would be to let people have unlimited credit.

I do understand the other example sentences for credit (sentences such as, "They are now dealing with damaged credit" or "His credit was good, so he didn’t expect the bank to reject his loan application"); but I have no idea what unlimited credit means here.

Comment: Perhaps you can give more context - what does "the idea" refer to?

Comment: If you have "unlimited credit" that means you can borrow as much as you want (there is no upper limit). ***Credit*** there specifically refers to *the amount of money you are authorised to borrow*. But in such contexts it might help you to think of it as being equivalent to ***creditworthiness***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle it means that the person would be allowed to borrow as much money as they desire.  In practice there is always *some* upper limit -- after all, the creditor does not have *unlimited* assets.

So, in effect, it's just a figure of speech to indicate the lending institution has the *greatest possible trust* in that person.